# How do I validate country and state/province names and postal codes?

Tags: php, validation, geolocation, location

I am building an web app (with PHP) that requires users to subscribe. I would like for them to identify where they are from. So what is the best way to validate there country/state(or province)/city/postal code? Is there a DB with all the information? Which one is the best?

Comment: for which country? ..also ..do you want to crosscheck street/postal codes ..or just verify the postcode exists?

Comment: Good question. All countries or as many as possible. "crosscheck street/postal codes" does that work well? Do you recommend it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Google Geocoding API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/)  They allow 2,500 requests per day and you can pay for more.  It will take an address and give you very detailed information on it and provide validation if you code it into your application.

Comment: For anyone seeing this afresh, this is from Googles terms: Note: the Geocoding API may only be used in conjunction with a Google map; geocoding results without displaying them on a map is prohibited. see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Answer (score 4):

There are many options for address validation. The main issue is how much traffic your website will receive and whether or not you need support. If you are relatively small, you can get away with the free services like the following:

- [Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/services.html#Geocoding_Structured) ([example](http://www.telnet80.com/2010/09/address-validation-using-google-maps.html)) (you may be breaking the [TOS](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html))
- [UPS Address Verification API](http://www.ups.com/bussol) ([example](http://www.varnagiris.net/2006/03/11/php-ups-address-validation-tool/))
- [USPS Address Web Tools](https://www.usps.com/business/webtools-address-information.htm?)

If you need something more robust or customizable, it will probably be necessary to pay for a service.

Comment: Just out of curiosity. Do you know any good robust/customizable services out there?

Comment: I have no experience with any services except Google Maps, but a quick look around revealed [SmartyStreets](http://www.smartystreets.com/). I cannot vouch for it's usefulness though.

Comment: I'm the founder of SmartyStreets and I can vouch for us!

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but to prevent others from going down the wrong path, the chosen answer to use Google API's may not have been aware of the [google terms of service license](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) (...the Geocoding API **may only be used in conjunction with a Google** map; geocoding results without displaying them on a map is prohibited.)

If you're not using a map...

and your requirements do not require commercial grade data, [this](http://greatdata.com/resources) sums up some options and what to look for.

however, if you need commercial data, [greatdata.com](http://greatdata.com) and [melissadata.com](http://melissadata.com) both sell real commercial level data products.

This thread is also helpful: [stackoverflow thread on zip code data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428889/lookup-county-name-using-address-city-state-and-zip/11140033#11140033)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [USPS Address Information API](https://www.usps.com/business/webtools.htm?).

Answer (score 0):

I've utilized data that can be purchased inexpensively from http://zipcodedownload.com/ to provide zip code validation/address correction in our applications.